# Inserting values in MySQL table using Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have a Bank table in MySQL with the following schema:

```
`User_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Amount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`)
```

I am trying to take Amount as input and enter a record in the table using Python. I run the following code for the same:

```
print " enter the bank amount"
Amount = raw_input()
cursor.execute('''INSERT into Bank (Amount)
                  values (%d)''',
                  (Amount))
cursor.execute('commit')
```

But, it shows following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_user.py", line 23, in <module>
    (Amount))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Answer (score 2):

[`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string:

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
>   without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
>   that.

```
>>> test = raw_input()
1
>>> test
'1'
>>> type(test)
<type 'str'>
```

You need to cast it to `int` (according to the `Amount` column type):

```
amount = int(raw_input())  # TODO: handle exceptions?

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO 
        Bank (Amount)
    VALUES 
        (%d)
""", (amount, ))

db.commit()
```

Comment: Byconverting string to int , it shows the following error             `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_user.py", line 23, in <module>
    (Amount ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
`

Comment: @noopurballal are you sure you're executing the same code as in the answer? Recheck it please.